# Information on a static part

Tags: kml, google-earth

I have write a km file which show a track on Google earth.I would like to show some information while track is playing,kind of a static balloon in corner of screen, but i have no idea how can i do this! is there any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In KML you can create a [Screen Overlay](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#screenoverlay) that is always visible and can be placed at any location of the screen.

A collection of samples is included in the Screen Overlays folder in the [KML Samples](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/KML_Samples.kml) file.

As an example, enable the "*Absolute Positioning: Top left*" folder in the KML Samples file and you will see a screen overlay at the top left of the view window. This was created with the following KML code:

```
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <ScreenOverlay>
    <name>Absolute Positioning: Top left</name>
    <Icon>
      <href>http://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/images/top_left.jpg</href>
    </Icon>
    <overlayXY x="0" y="1" xunits="fraction" yunits="fraction"/>
    <screenXY x="0" y="1" xunits="fraction" yunits="fraction"/>
    <rotationXY x="0" y="0" xunits="fraction" yunits="fraction"/>
    <size x="0" y="0" xunits="fraction" yunits="fraction"/>
  </ScreenOverlay>
</kml>
```

The `overlayXY` is an anchor position within the overlay that is mapped onto the `screenXY`, which is the position on the screen. The x and y values can be specified in three different ways: as pixels ("pixels"), as fractions of the image ("fraction"), or as inset pixels ("insetPixels"), which is an offset in pixels from the upper right corner of the image.

If you're creating a KML tour then you can control when the ScreenOverlay is visible and turn it on/off as needed.

This [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20844076/text-overlay-in-google-earth-kml) shows a trick using the Google Chart API to dynamically display text in a ScreenOverlay.

For more details see the [Screen Overlay Tutorial](http://www.google.com/earth/outreach/tutorials/screenoverlays.html).

Comment: Thanks for answer, i have already read this before but i need to change data in every moment of my track!