# Show text on KmlLayer Android

Tags: android, google-maps, kml

Is there any way to show placemark name on polygon.

[image]

I am doing this using GroundOverlayOptions.

```
GroundOverlayOptions newarkMap = new GroundOverlayOptions()
                                .image(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(textAsBitmap(placemark.getProperty("name"))))
                                .position(polyBuilder.build().getCenter(), 860f, 650f);
                        groundOverlay = map.addGroundOverlay(newarkMap);
```

But, I am having issue with text size. Where region is on "N" character.

[image]

Is there any other way to show placemark name on polygon using kml.

Comment: Do you want the text aligned with the polygon or fixed on the screen?

Comment: want to show text on polygon. I want to show region name on polygon. I have name, but i dont know how to show on polygon.

Comment: Have you tried a MultiGeomtry with a Point as described in the answer below?

Comment: I am getting kml file without MultiGeometry from server side.

Comment: GroundOverlay with Text as image is the other way to annotation map with text at particular geo-location.

Answer (score 0):

By default you only see the name label if your placemark has a Point geometry so for polygons (and lines) the name is not shown.

You can, however, create a [MultiGeometry](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#multigeometry) with both a Polygon and a Point geometry (typically the center point or where you want to label to appear near). If you don't want the default yellow pushpin to appear just add a Style with an empty IconStyle href element to the Placemark.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
    <Placemark>
        <name>polygon</name>
        <Style>
            <IconStyle>
                <Icon/>
            </IconStyle>
        </Style>
        <MultiGeometry>
            <Point>
                <coordinates>-122.4317195,37.801848</coordinates>
            </Point>
            <Polygon>
                <outerBoundaryIs>
                    <LinearRing>
                        <coordinates>
              -122.43193945401,37.801983684521
              -122.43156413110,37.802032773140
              -122.43149953649,37.801715236748
              -122.43187136387,37.801663491544
              -122.43193945401,37.801983684521
                        </coordinates>
                    </LinearRing>
                </outerBoundaryIs>
            </Polygon>
        </MultiGeometry>
    </Placemark>
</kml>
```

Alternatively, if you want to add text to the map at a fixed screen location via your KML then you could create a [ScreenOverlay](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#screenoverlay). This [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20844076/text-overlay-in-google-earth-kml) shows a trick using the Google Chart API to dynamically display text in a ScreenOverlay.